# Inserting a link in the message while publishing feed on facebook

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using the PHP SDK from facebook in my application. When I'm publishing a news feed and inserting a link in the message as HTML anchor tag, it just wont shows up. I understand that a regular HTML anchor is not the way to do this. so, is there a right way to insert a link in a feed message?
* is there a way to control (like html tags) the message field when posting feed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook removes any HTML from messages posted to feed. You can have link in three different places though: name, attachment and action link.

Answer (score 0):

Try read this. http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/stream.publish

Comment: Thanks, But the 'stream.publish' is deprecated. I need to use the api as '/uid/feed/', param_array...